# Resize Event Not Firing On Every Click

Tags: function, events, onclick, resize, slick.js

The resize event I created to show my slick sliders' images in my modal is only firing once on the initial width. If I close the modal, manually move the width of the window, and open the modal again, the images aren't resized. Therefore, they don't appear.

HTML:

```
<section>
<button id='show' onClick='showDialog()'><img src="img./(This is where I put the name of my image).jpg"style="width:100%;max-width: 400px"></button>
<div id='dialog'>
  <span>
    <div id="mySlickSlider">
        <div class="mySlide">
        (This is where I included the images in my slick slider)
        </div>
    </div>
  </span>
<button id='close' onClick='closeDialog()'>&times;</button>
</div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$('#show').on('click', function(e){
  $('#mySlickSlider').resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the resize function was not working, I used a timeout function for the different classes that comprised my slick slider and set it to 0 so there was no lag.

```
$(window).on('click', function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.mySlideNav').slick("getSlick").refresh();
     $('.mySlide').slick("getSlick").refresh();
  },0);
});
```